# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \sin\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \right)^{\alpha}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I am trying to seek the real values of $\alpha$ for convergence of the following series :
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \sin\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \right)^{\alpha}$

My trial:
Since $n>1$, $0<\frac{1}{n}<1$, thus we can expand sin function as
\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) = \frac{1}{n}  - \frac{1}{3!} \frac{1}{n^3} + \cdots
\end{align}
Hence the series becomes
\begin{align}
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n} - \sin\left(\frac{1}{n} \right) \right)^{\alpha} 
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{3!}\frac{1}{n^3} - \cdots\right)^{\alpha} \leq \frac{1}{3!}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3\alpha}
\end{align}
Thus my guess is from p-test $3\alpha >1$, i.e., $\alpha>\frac{1}{3}$.

Is this approach admissible?

Comment: I think your approach works but you have to prove it rigorously .

Comment: @DeepSea, that's the problem! I want to know what process is needed for rigorous proof!

Comment: The limit comparison test is the way to go: if $a_n, b_n > 0$ and $a_n/b_n \to c \in (0, \infty)$ as $n\to \infty$ then $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ either both converge or both diverge.

Comment: You can use the fact that the sin series is enveloping, so that $x > x-x^3/6+ x^5/120> \sin(x) > x-x^3/6$.

Comment: The power of $1/n$ in the majorant should be $3\alpha$ and not $\alpha/3$.

Comment: @Gary thanks! I just edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct for using the Taylor expansion of $\sin x$ around $x=0$. Note that for large enough $n$:
$$
{1\over n}-{1\over 6n^3}\le\sin {1\over n}\le {1\over n}-{1\over 5n^3}
$$
You have already done the lower bound. The upper bound is just on its way!